# Retrieve variable inside script tag with xpath query

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, xpath

I am trying to retrieve a variable (vin=5J8TC2H69KL805815) inside a script tag with a xpath query for practice. 
The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var enterprise_id = 6731892;
        var dealertrackSettings = {"LowestPaymentWidgetParameters":"prtnr=EDLR&pdid=&jrr=9Z8758kQMpewxBhu8abpaBXX&lang=en&zip=T4R2N7&vin=5J8TC2H69KL805815&acode=CAC90ACS121C0&yr=2019&mk=Acura&model=RDX&style=SUV&trim=A-Spec&cond=U&kms=14,709&cp=52365&msrp=52365&hash=f8842e17a06af7c979d16db0980afbec28c808617e80db2260364c37235b9b25&pkg=&disp=2.0L&opt=&trans=AT&drv=All Wheel Drive&fuelType=Gasoline&eng=2.0L 4cyl&mcode=","DigitalRetailingWidgetParameters":"?flow=full&token=df387c15-9b3d-4694-b06f-fccdfbc8a437&lang=en&prtnr=EDLR&pdid=&zip=T4R2N7&vin=5J8TC2H69KL805815&msrp=52365&cp=52365&asst=AU&cond=U&yr=2019&mk=Acura&model=RDX&style=SUV&trim=A-Spec&tab=TRADE&jrr=9Z8758kQMpewxBhu8abpaBXX&hash=f8842e17a06af7c979d16db0980afbec28c808617e80db2260364c37235b9b25&kms=14,709&acode=CAC90ACS121C0&pkg=&disp=2.0L&opt=&trans=AT&drv=All Wheel Drive&fuelType=Gasoline&eng=2.0L 4cyl&mcode=","LowestPaymentWidgetAPIJson":null,"useUAT":false,"Domain":"https:\/\/digital.dealertrack.ca","displayAFFCTAUsed":true,"displayStructureMyDealCTAUsed":true,"structureMyDealBackgroundUsed":null,"displayFinancePrequalifyCTAUsed":true,"drivetrainMap":{"FRONT WHEEL DRIVE":"FWD","REAR WHEEL DRIVE":"RWD","AWD EXT":"AWD","N\/A":""},"transmissionMap":{"AUTOMATIC":"AT","MANUAL":"MT","OTHER":""}};
    </script>
```

I narrowed down the text from the script tag like so and this 
brings back the text.

```
//script[contains(text(), 'dealertrackSettings')]/text()
```

but from this a im kinda confused on how to proceed. Any suggestions appreciated. Tahnks

edit: I am trying to do this in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath should be able to get the script content, I've used `evaluate()` as it is just a string you want.  Then I've used a `regex()` to extract the `vin=...` part.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$script = $xp->evaluate("string(//script[contains(text(), 'dealertrackSettings')]/text())");
if ( preg_match("/(vin=\w*)/", $script, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

which gives

```
vin=5J8TC2H69KL805815
```

If you just want the value, then change the regex to `/vin=(\w*)/`, this only captures the value and not the `vin=` part as well.

```
5J8TC2H69KL805815
```